# How to make a copy of all data contained within a ROS topic message?

Tags: turtlebot, ros-groovy, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to write a node that subscribes to the kinect data from multiple turtlebots, then concatenates/averages the data, and republishes the resulting single data stream to rviz as part of a larger program intended to map a room cooperatively with multiple turtlebots at once.

I've already written a node that subscribes to kinect data from multiple turtlebots, but now am struggling with the republishing.  I have several callback methods that are call every time a message is published on a certain topic, and within each of these callback methods, I would like to copy all the data contained within the message to a temporary global variable which can then be accessed in the main class.  However, the only way I can think of to do this is to go through and manually copy each individual piece of data from the message to the global variable.  Is there a simpler way to do this?  For example, is there a command that I could use to create a copy of each message within each callback function, which I could call and then just modify whatever parts I wanted to modify, instead of having to manually copy each data piece?

Edit:
Yes, I am using C++.  Here is the odometry (location/heading) callback function.  RIght now it just prints out the relevant data:

```
void OdomCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry locator)
{
  ROS_INFO("Position: %f,%f", locator.pose.pose.position.x,locator.pose.pose.position.y);
  ROS_INFO("Heading: linear:%f,angular:%f", locator.twist.twist.linear.x,locator.twist.twist.angular.z);
}
```

So you're saying that in order to copy the message I would add in a line like this?
nav_msgs::Odometry globalLocationVariable=locator;

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147236/how-to-make-a-copy-of-all-data-contained-within-a-ros-topic-message?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using C++? You can simply copy the data into a new object? Like

```
FooMsg copy = callbackMsg;
```

It would look a bit different if you use pointer instead of references in your callbacks. Can you edit your question to include some sample code (at least one of the callbacks)?

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1